# Return ResultSet in try with resources java.sql.SQLException: Operation not allowed after ResultSet closed

Tags: java, mysql, swing, jdbc, resultset

I have a file called CustomerController will get the ResultSet return from the MyConnectToMySQL then add to the ArrayList

I am switching to Try-with-Resources Because I want to make sure it is closed and I don't want close by each time I run something (BTW sometimes it is bugged and didn't close make my app slow).

The old one worked fine. But when I switched to Try-with-resources the error start appears

```
java.sql.SQLException: Operation not allowed after ResultSet closed
```

AFAIK, This is because Try-with-resources closed the connection after it has done so when I return the ResultSet it is inaccessible.
So my solution right now is to make a connection inside my CustomerController and when I get the resultSet I add it to the ArrayList before closing.

Are there any ideas about this problem? I don't want to merge it to CustomerController (will work, I think) because I want to reuse it in my future with other Controller.

```
    public class CustomerController {
        MyConnectToMySQL conn = null;
        ResultSet rs = null;
        ArrayList<nguoidungDTO> dsnd = null;
    
        public CustomerController () {
            if (conn == null) {
                conn = new MyConnectUnit("localhost", "root", "", "thuvien");
            }
        }
    
        public ArrayList<nguoidungDTO> docDSND() throws Exception {
            dsnd = new ArrayList<nguoidungDTO>();
            rs = conn.excuteQuery("SELECT * FROM nguoidung");
            while (rs.next()) {
                nguoidungDTO nguoidung = new nguoidungDTO();
                nguoidung.setManv(rs.getString(1));
                nguoidung.setMkhau(rs.getString(2));
                nguoidung.setQuyen(rs.getString(3));
                dsnd.add(nguoidung);
            }
//Old, each time I have done used, I will close by hand
            //conn.Close();
            return dsnd;
        }
    }
```

MyConnectToMySQL

```
    package DAO;
    
    import java.sql.Connection;
    import java.sql.DriverManager;
    import java.sql.ResultSet;
    import java.sql.SQLException;
    import java.sql.Statement;
    
    public class MyConnectToMySQL {
    
        String Host = "";
        String UserName = "";
        String Password = "";
        String Database = "";
    
        Connection connect = null;
        Statement statement = null;
        ResultSet rs = null;
    
        public MyConnectToMySQL(String Host, String UserName, String Password, String Database) {
            this.Host = Host;
            this.UserName = UserName;
            this.Password = Password;
            this.Database = Database;
        }
    
        public void DriverTest() throws Exception {
            try {
                Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
            } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
                throw new Exception("MySQL Driver JDBC not found");
            }
        }
    //old
        protected Connection getConnection() throws Exception {
            if (this.connect == null) {
                DriverTest();
                String url = "jdbc:mysql://" + this.Host + ":3306/" + this.Database
                        + "?autoReconnect=true&useSSL=false&useUnicode=true&characterEncoding=UTF-8";
                try {
                    this.connect = DriverManager.getConnection(url, this.UserName, this.Password);
                } catch (SQLException e) {
                    throw new Exception("Can't coonect MySQL server " + e);
                }
            }
            return this.connect;
        }
    //old
        protected Statement getStatement() throws Exception {
            
            if (this.statement == null ? true : this.statement.isClosed()) {
                
                this.statement = this.getConnection().createStatement();
            }
            return this.statement;
        }
    
    //Old
        /*public ResultSet excuteQuery(String query) throws Exception {
            try {
                this.rs = getStatement().executeQuery(query);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                throw new Exception("Error : " + e.getMessage());
            }
            
            return this.rs;
        }*/
        
    //Switching to Try-With-Resources
        public ResultSet excuteQuery(String query) throws Exception  {
            DriverTest();
            String url = "jdbc:mysql://" + this.Host + ":3306/" + this.Database
                    + "?autoReconnect=true&useSSL=false&useUnicode=true&characterEncoding=UTF-8";
            ResultSet myResult = null;
            try(Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection(url, this.UserName, this.Password);
                     Statement statement = con.createStatement();
                    ) {
                try (ResultSet res = statement.executeQuery(query)) {
                    myResult = res;
                    
                    System.out.println(myResult);
                    return myResult;
                    }
                } catch (SQLException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
    //Must return here too
    return myResult;
            }
        
            public void Close() throws Exception {
                if (this.rs != null && !this.rs.isClosed()) {
                    this.rs.close();
           }
            if (this.statement != null && !this.statement.isClosed()) {
                this.statement.closed();
            }
            if (this.connect != null && !this.connect.isClosed()) {
                this.connect.closed();
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: KorbirT - Any update?

Comment: Still looking for more answers.

Comment: Your method should not attempt to return a `ResultSet`. This already is an attemped leak, but it fails for the reason stated in the exception. Neither the `ResultSet` nor the `Statement` nor even the `Connection` should be instance variables. They should all be local variables. Otherwise (a) your class isn't thread-safe, (b) you are liable to run into closed connections because of them being open long-term, and (c) you run into problems like this. It follows that you shouldn't have `getConnection(), getStatement()`, or `Close()` either. You need to radically reconsider all this.

Answer (score 1):

When you use [try-with-resources](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html), the resource is closed once the `try` block is finished. After that, if you try to close it explicitly, you will get the error. You are doing:

```
this.rs.close();
```

which will cause the issue if this statement is invoked. It is because you have created `Connection`, `Statement` and `Resultset` using `try-with-resources`.

Make sure that the method, `public void Close()` is not called or better you remove the above-mentioned statement from this method to avoid accidentally invoking it when you use/call this method for some other purposes.

I can also see the following lines in your code:

```
this.statement.closed();
this.connect.closed();
```

This will cause compilation failure as neither `java.sql.Connection` nor `java.sql.Statement` has a `closed()` method. Probably, you wanted to type `close()`. However, make sure you remove these statements for the same reason which is mentioned above.

Comment: My first version is closing by hand with conn.Close() with the Captical C (sorry for bad naming), called at the end of each CustomerController method.
I have commented that line when I switch to Try-with-resources, so this method not should be execute anymore.

I will delete that method and try again when I get home